# Django tutorial part2 went wrong

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm following the tutorial and I received a traceback ~>

```
Question.objects.all()Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: polls_question The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: Traceback (most recent call last): File "<console>", line 1, in <module> File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __repr__ data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1]) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 262, in __len__ self._fetch_all() File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self)) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__ results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql cursor.execute(sql, params) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute return super().execute(sql, params) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers return executor(sql, params, many, context) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__ raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: polls_question >>> from django.utils import timezone >>> q = Question(question_text="What's new?", pub_date=timezone.now()) >>> q.save() Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: polls_question The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: Traceback (most recent call last): File "<console>", line 1, in <module> File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 726, in save self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 763, in save_base updated = self._save_table(b/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 868, in _save_table results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 906, in _do_insert return manager._insert( File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1270, in _insert return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1416, in execute_sql cursor.execute(sql, params) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute return super().execute(sql, params) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers return executor(sql, params, many, context) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__ raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: polls_question
```

I did the makemigrations and migrate, nothing changed or helped.
After I included at db.sqlite3 by hand the tables and that gave me another traceback ~>

```
Question.objects.all()Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: polls_question.question_textThe above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:Traceback (most recent call last): File "<console>", line 1, in <module> File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __repr__ data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1]) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 262, in __len__ self._fetch_all() File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self)) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__ results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql cursor.execute(sql, params) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute return super().execute(sql, params) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers return executor(sql, params, many, context) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__ raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: polls_question.question_text >>> Question.objects.all() Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: polls_question.question_text The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: Traceback (most recent call last): File "<console>", line 1, in <module> File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __repr__ data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1]) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 262, in __len__ self._fetch_all() File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self)) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__ results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql cursor.execute(sql, params) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute return super().execute(sql, params) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers return executor(sql, params, many, context) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__ raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) File "/home/pingounica/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: polls_question.question_text
```

that's my models.py ~>

```
from django.db import models


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

def __str__(self):
    return self.question_text


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

and my manage.py ~>

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you created your app using the command `manage.py startapp polls` but I see `mysite` in your `manage.py`

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
```

Django creates the table names in the database using a combination of the app name and the model name. In your case the app name is supposed to be `polls` I believe?, but for some reason the app name in your `manage.py` is `mysite`.

I suggest you start from scratch and try again with the `manage.py startapp <app name>` command, be careful of changing any references to the actual app name manually in any of the generated files.